# Syntax error while using multiple rename RENAME expressions postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, alter-table

I'm trying to write a query that RENAMEs multiple table columns at once. According to the documentation, the syntax is:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
RENAME old_col_a AS new_col_a
, RENAME old_col_b AS new_col_b...;
```

However, in doing so I get a syntax error located on the comma after the first RENAME clause:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 3: , RENAME 
    ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1
```

The query works for multiple DROP/ALTER/ADD columns and for single RENAMEs. I just can't for the life of me figure out why this error is occurring.

Comment: What does the manual say?

Comment: If you're following http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-rename-column/ its sssertion that multiple simultaneous renames are possible seems to be at odds with the official docs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use multiple `ALTER` statements:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
RENAME COLUMN old_col_a TO new_col_a;

ALTER TABLE table_name
RENAME COLUMN old_col_b TO new_col_b;
```

> [ALTER TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-altertable.html)
>
> **All the forms of ALTER TABLE that act on a single table, except RENAME, SET SCHEMA, ATTACH PARTITION, and DETACH PARTITION can be combined into a list of multiple alterations to be applied together.** For example, it is possible to add several columns and/or alter the type of several columns in a single command. This is particularly useful with large tables, since only one pass over the table need be made.